# Combinatorial sequences whose ratios $a_{n+1}/a_{n}$ are integers

Tags: co.combinatorics, big-list

I have a proof technique in search of examples. I'm looking for combinatorially meaningful sequences $\{a_n\}$ so that $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is known or conjectured to be an integer, such that there is a relation between the $n$th case and $n+1$st, but **not** an obvious $a_{n+1}/a_n\to 1$ map. This means $a_n$ is the $n$th partial product of an infinite sequence of integers, but there isn't an obvious product structure.

- The prototype was an enumeration of
  domino tilings of an [Aztec
  diamond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aztec_diamond) of order $n$, $a_n =
     2^{n(n+1)/2}$, so $a_{n+1}/a_n =
     2^{n+1}$. (There is a nice $2^{n+1}$
  to 1 map unrelated to my technique,
  but it isn't obvious.)
- Another application was a proof that
  $\det \{B_{i+j}\}_{i,j=0}^n =
     \prod_{i=1}^n i! $  where $B_n$ is
  the $n$th [Bell number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellNumber.html), equation
  25 in the linked page.
- The counts of alternating sign matrices 1, 2, 7, 42, ... are **not** an example, since 
  $ASM(n+1)/ASM(n) = \frac{ (3n+1)!n!}{2n! (2n+1)!}$ which is not always an integer, e.g,     7/2 is not.

> What are some other interesting combinatorial families whose ratios $a_{n+1}/a_n$ are known or (preferably) conjectured to be integers?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you seeking counterexamples to the idea that $a_n | a_{n+1}$
for all $n$ ought to imply an $(a_{n+1}/a_n)$-to-1, or challenges
where no such map is known but there may be a nice construction?

Comment: Oh, and what's the combinatorial meaning of the Bell determinant?

Comment: You may be right that this should be community wiki. I'm looking for possible families of combinatorial objects for which one might not be able to construct $a_{n+1}/a_n:1$ maps easily, but for which one might still be able to prove such a ratio. For domino tilings of Aztec diamonds, the proof is by overlaying a pattern of dominoes to make a domino tiling correspond to a family of nonintersecting lattice paths, enumerated using the Gessel-Viennot-Lindstrom determinant, then factoring the matrix as $LDU$, where $D$ turns out to be $\text{Diag}(2,4,8,...)$. There are $2^{n+1}:1$ maps known...

Comment: I don't know of a direct combinatorial interpretation of the Bell number determinant, but there is a similar factorization of the matrix so that the diagonal matrix is $\text{Diag}(0!,1!, ..., n!)$. I don't recall the lower triangular and upper triangular pieces exactly, but they are in the OEIS, and proving the factorization was a simple combinatorial exercise, something involving set partitions with a marked element.

Comment: Now I remember the factorization. Set partitions of a set of size $i+j$ are in bijection with a disjoint union over $t=0,1,2,...$ of set partitions of the first $i$ elements with $t$ parts marked, set partitions of the last $j$ elements with $t$ parts marked, and the $t!$ bijections between the marked parts to be glued together. That proves the $LDL^T$ decomposition. The number of partitions of a set of size $i$ with $i$ parts marked is $1$, so the lower diagonal matrix $L$ has $1$s on the diagonal and determinant $1$. That proves that the Bell number determinant is $\prod_{t=0}^n t!$.

Comment: For derangements we know $D_n=nD_{n-1}+(-1)^n$ and there is an "almost" $n$ to $1$ map which proves this. The map is almost a bijection from $D_{n-1}\times\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ to $D_n$ but either leaves one thing in the domain unmapped or one thing in the range unhit. Perhaps there are situations like this where your question makes sense. $\sum_k\binom{n}{3k}=\frac{2^n\pm1}{3}$  $1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 11, 22, 43, 85, 170, 341, 683, 1366,\cdots$ So the ratio is always $2$ , sometimes with a defect of $\pm 1.$

Answer (score 20):

The number of pairs $(P,Q)$ of standard Young tableaux of the same shape and with $n$ squares is $n!$.

The number of oscillating tableaux of length $2n$ and empty shape is $1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-1)$.

The number of leaf-labeled complete (unordered) binary trees with $n$ leaves is $1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots (2n-3)$ (Schröder's third problem).

The number of compact-rooted directed animals of size $n$ is $3^n$. See MathSciNet MR0956559 (90c:05009).

Let $f(n)$ be the number of $n\times n$ matrices $M=(m_{ij})$ of nonnegative integers with row and column sum vector $(1,3,6,\dots,{n+1\choose 2})$ such that $m_{ij}=0$ if $j>i+1$. Then $f(n)=C_1C_2\cdots C_n$, where $C_i$ is a Catalan number. No combinatorial proof of this result is known. See Exercise 6.C12 on page 38 (solution on page 84) of http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/catadd.pdf

Comment: Thanks for these examples! I'll let you know if I can get the technique to work. 

Comment: Any luck, Douglas?

Comment: Recent article related to last example: https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.00701

Answer (score 7):

There are 345 sequences in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=name%3Aquotient) qith the word “quotient” in their names, does that help?

Answer (score 4):

Let a<sub>n</sub> be the largest power of 2 that divides R<sub>n</sub>, the number of reduced Latin squares of order n.  We know the value of a<sub>n</sub> for n≤11 (see [this](http://combinatoricswiki.org/wiki/Enumeration_of_Latin_Squares_and_Rectangles) for example).  The sequence begins (1,1,1,2<sup>2</sup>,2<sup>3</sup>,2<sup>6</sup>,2<sup>10</sup>,2<sup>17</sup>,2<sup>21</sup>,2<sup>28</sup>,2<sup>35</sup>,...) for n≥1.

I wouldn't conjecture that a<sub>n+1</sub>/a<sub>n</sub> is always an integer (although, it seems plausible).  However, we do know that a<sub>n+1</sub>/a<sub>n</sub> is an integer for 1≤n≤10.

Answer (score 3):

The number of $n$-block domino towers is $3^{n-1}$. The simplest bijective proof uses the fact that for the Motzkin generating function $M=M(z)$ we have $$\frac{M}{(1-zM)^2}=\frac{1}{1-3z}.$$ See pages 19-21 of this paper (and the references there):

http://math.sfsu.edu/federico/Clase/AC/algmethods.pdf

(This is Chapter 1 in the Handbook of Enumerative Combinatorics.)

Likewise, the number of pairs of grand Dyck paths of combined semilength $n$ is $4^n$.

Answer (score 1):

The number of acyclic orientations on the complete graph on $n$ vertices is $n!$, and the number of acyclic orientation on a unit-interval graph on $n$ vertices is given by a product with $n$ factors, so you can easily construct many sequences from this.

Answer (score -2):

If you take a(n)=2^F(n);a(n+1)=2^F(n+1) , where F(n+1) ,F(n) are Fibonacci numbers and F(n+1)=F(n)+F(n-1) , then a(n+1)/a(n)=2^[F(n+1)-F(n)]=2^F(n-1)
Fibonacci series S=[n_F(n)]=(0_0),(1_1),(2_1),(3_2),(4_3),(5_5),(6_8),(7_13),(8_21),(9_34)...
Product {a(n+1)/a(n)}*{a(n)/a(n-1)}*...{a(3)/a(2)}*{a(2)/a(1)}=a(n+1)/a(1)
       =2^{F(n-1)+F(n-2)+...+F(1)+F(0)} =2^{F(n+1)-1}=2^F(n+1)/2
Example=>
(2^21/2^13)*(2^13/2^8)*(2^8/2^5)*(2^5/2^3)*(2^3/2^2)*(2^2/2^1)*(2^1/2^1)=2^21/2
 =(2^8)*(2^5)*(2^3)*(2^2)*(2^1)*(2^1)=2^(8+5+3+2+1+1)=2^20

I hope this  example   suits to your needs.

Comment: Does this count something which doesn't have a clear product structure?